# querying mongodb subarray and returning only the latest item in the subarray that fits a date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schemas (removed most fields for readability):

```
const BudgetItemHistorySchema = new Schema({
  amount: Number,
  modifiedOn: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
})

const BudgetItemSchema = new Schema({
  projectId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  amount: Number,
  history: {
    type: [BudgetItemHistorySchema],
    default: []
  }
});
```

I need a query that would return only the most recent item from the `history` sub-array, given if I run a query of:

```
BudgetItem.find({
    'projectId': 'abc123',
    'history.modifiedOn': {
        $gte: "<fromDate>",
        $lte: "<toDate>"
    }
});
```

I would return multiple `BudgetItems`, that may have 0 or more `history` items.

So, if there is more than 1 item in the `history` array, only return the most recent item, given the date range.

I know that I will need to use the aggregation pipeline, but I am struggling to construct a query that would only return the `$last` item of the subarray.

I know how to do this if I was returning the `$last` of the BudgetItems, as specified in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/, but how to do this with subarrays?

An example output would be:

```
[{
    'projectId': 'abc123',
    'amount': 100,
    'history': [{
        '_id': 'aabbcc',
        'amount': 75,
        'modifiedOn': '<latestDate>'
    }]
},{
    'projectId': 'abc123',
    'amount': 700,
    'history': [{
        '_id': 'ccddee',
        'amount': 600,
        'modifiedOn': '<latestDate>'
    }]
}]
```

but, a more preferable output would simply be:

```
[{
    'projectId': 'abc123',
    '_id': 'aabbcc',
    'amount': 75,
    'modifiedOn': '<latestDate>'
},{
    'projectId': 'abc123',
    '_id': 'ccddee',
    'amount': 600,
    'modifiedOn': '<latestDate>'
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
db.BudgetItem.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "projectId" : "abc123"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields : {
            history : {
                $filter : { 
                    input: "$history", 
                    cond: { 
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: [ "$$this.modifiedOn", ISODate("2019-10-01") ] },
                            { $lte: [ "$$this.modifiedOn", ISODate("2020-10-15") ] }
                        ] 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields : {
            history : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$history", -1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "projectId": 1,
            "_id": "$history._id",
            "amount": "$history.amount",
            "modifiedOn": "$history.modifiedOn"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks so much. In addition, what if I wanted to query another history element in the same aggregation pipeline, with the same filter, except a different modifiedOn dates (say, 1 month back), and add it to the projection. I tried doing another $addFields: { previousHistory: { ... }, but something tells me I have been unable to preserve the original $history ... hope I'm making sense - basically, an additional attribute to the $project: { secondHistory: { amount: ..., modifiedOn: ... } } ... I just want to be able to includer two time periods.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding your situation correctly.. Is this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YxOwSYMpHEz) what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly that :) ... I almost had it, but separated out the pipeline into two different $addFields :)